# Different behavior Telegram API for different telegram accounts

Tags: telegram, mtproto

I have two telegram accounts registered for two phone numbers. When I login to telegram data center with my first account, I can use method `users.getFullUser` to get information about any user. Likewise, I can use method `messages.sendMessage` to send a message to any user.

But, if I login with my second account, error `400 USER_ID_INVALID` occurs when I use the method `users.getFullUser` for any user_id, excluding my own (for own user_id the method returns correct result). Likewise, method `messages.sendMessage` rises error `400 PEER_ID_INVALID`, if I try to send a message to any user except me (if I send message to myself, the method works as expected).

Why is such different behavior possible and how can I get the API to work correctly for the second account?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.